# ten-commandments tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I just tagged a question about taking God's name in vain with [commandments](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commandments).  Even though this question is just about one of the Ten Commandments, should it be tagged with [ten-commandments](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ten-commandments), or is [commandments](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commandments) okay?  Should it be a singular form?

[Is saying "Oh My God" really using God's name in vain?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/952/is-saying-oh-my-god-really-using-gods-name-in-vain)

Comment: why not tag as both?

Answer (score 10):

There are plenty of places where we're commanded to do/not do certain things.  But the Ten Commandments are a well-known category of their own, so it would probably be a good idea to tag it as ten-commandments.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe we should break this down to first-commandment, second-commandment?

Comment: And what is the seventh commandment? http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/502/why-are-there-different-divisions-of-the-ten-commandments